# Insert a single view inside a listview makes listItem non clickable

Tags: java, android

I am inflating a view inside a list item on listItemClick .The list item contains a check box. When the check box is clicked a linear layout containing  two/three edit text fields and buttons gets inflated to that list view ( done by getView method of cursor adapter, the inflating view is dynamically created ) .

the list view is registered with on item click listener . After the layout being inflated , the onItemClick Listener is not getting called for the particular item. Help me

my getView code

```
TextView text1  = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.text);
        text1.setText("text");

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxList) ;
        cb.setTag(tag);
        cb.setChecked(false);

        if ( chekedIdVector.contains(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID) )))
        {
            cb.setChecked(true);
        }

        if( !idVector.isEmpty () )
        {
            LinearLayout ll =(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutinCell);

            if ( ((String)idVector.lastElement()).equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID) )) )
            {

                if (ll.getChildCount() == 0 )
                {
                    ll.removeAllViews() ;
                    ll.addView(dynamicallyCreatedView); // view dynamically created with 2/3 textviews and buttons
                }

                ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                view.requestFocus() ;
            }

            else
            {
                ll.removeAllViews() ;
            }
        }

        return view  ;
```

Ps: I have tried on focus changed listener  and set the check box to non focusable in xml

Comment: What is `view`? How are you searching inside `view` to find the `LinearLayout`, then adding `view` as a child of this `LinearLayout`? `view` can't be both the parent and the child of `ll`.

Comment: @user113215 the view is parameter from getView() method in cursor adapter. the child view is dynamicallyCreatedView . I have edited it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, consider using an ExpandableListView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) or inflating the items from the start with the android:visibility="GONE" and then setting it as "VISIBLE" instead of inflating them.

Comment: I tried setting views to visible and gone , .. the problem is the listItem with Visible inflated view does not receive onItemClickListener. :::